# How to check node name of tensorflow graph (protocol buffers) by c++

Tags: c++, tensorflow, protocol-buffers

I want to check the loading graph is correct.

I save the learned protocol buffers file by python.
And, I load the protocol buffers file by c++.

But I can't get the output tensor when the session run.

I want to output and check the graph information.

**Saveing code by python**

```
with tf.Graph().as_default() as graph:
    input_data = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=train_data.shape, name="input")
    keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)

    answer = net.inference(input_data, units, io_data_dim, keep_prob, output_net=True)
    saver = tf.train.Saver()

    with tf.Session() as sess:

        # Load model file
        sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
        ckpt = tf.train.get_checkpoint_state(ckpt_dir_name)
        if ckpt: # checkpoint is exist
            last_model = ckpt.model_checkpoint_path # last model path
            saver.restore(sess, last_model)
        else:
            print("There is no training network...")
            exit()

        # check the saveing graph
        for v in sess.graph.get_operations():
            print(v.name)

        graph_def = graph_util.convert_variables_to_constants(sess, graph.as_graph_def(), ['output_lay/output_lay'])

        tf.train.write_graph(graph_def, '.', pb_name, as_text=False)
```

**Loading code by C++**

```
Status LoadGraph(string graph_file_name, std::unique_ptr<tensorflow::Session>* session) {
    tensorflow::GraphDef graph_def;
    Status graph_status = ReadBinaryProto(tensorflow::Env::Default(), graph_file_name, &graph_def);
    if (!graph_status.ok())
    {
        return graph_status;
    }
    session->reset(tensorflow::NewSession(tensorflow::SessionOptions()));
    Status create_status = (*session)->Create(graph_def);
    if (!create_status.ok())
    {
        return create_status;
    }
    return Status::OK();
}
```

**Runing code by c++**

input_node_name = "input"

output_node_name = "output_lay/output_lay"

```
Status Infer(std::unique_ptr<tensorflow::Session>* session,
    tensorflow::Tensor* input,
    string* input_node_name,
    string* output_node_name,
    tensorflow::Tensor* output)
{
    tensorflow::Tensor input_object = *input;

    // input
    // I am not confident here
    tensorflow::Tensor keep_prob(tensorflow::DT_FLOAT, tensorflow::TensorShape());
    keep_prob.scalar<float>()() = 1.0;


    std::vector<std::pair<string, tensorflow::Tensor>> inputs = {
        {"Placeholder", keep_prob},
        {*input_node_name, *input}
    };

    // ouput
    std::vector<tensorflow::Tensor> outputs;

    std::cout << "Runnning network..." << std::endl;

    Status result = (*session)->Run(
        inputs,
        {*output_node_name},
        {},
        &outputs
        );
    // output 0 (no reply?)
    std::cout << "outputs size " << outputs.size() << std::endl;

    if (!result.ok())
    {
        LOG(ERROR) << "Failure: " << result;
    }
    (*output) = outputs[0];
    //std::cout << "take first output" << std::endl;
    return result;
}
```

**result** is

Invalid argument: Incompatible shapes: **[77,1,513,16] vs. [13780,1,513,16]**
     [[Node: conv1/dropout/mul = Mul[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](conv1/dropout/Div, conv1/dropout/Floor)]]

ex) if not use the cnn ( the 3 layer perceptron network)
Invalid argument: Incompatible shapes: **[77,600] vs. [10242,600]**
     [[Node: hidden1/dropout/mul = Mul[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](hidden1/dropout/Div, hidden1/dropout/Floor)]]

**pickup of the output 1st python code**

- input
- Placeholder
- Reshape/shape
- Reshape
- conv1/weights
- conv1/biases
- conv1/Conv2D
- conv1/MaxPool
- conv1/Add
- conv1/conv1
- conv1/dropout/Shape
- conv1/dropout/add
- conv1/dropout/Floor
- conv1/dropout/Div
- conv1/dropout/mul
- conv2/weights
- conv2/biases
- conv2/Conv2D
- ...
- Reshape_1/shape
- Reshape_1
- hidden1/weights
- hidden1/biases
- hidden1/MatMul
- hidden1/Add
- hidden1/hidden1
- hidden1/dropout/add
- hidden1/dropout/Floor
- hidden1/dropout/Div
- hidden1/dropout/mul
- hidden2/weights
- ...
- output_lay/weights
- output_lay/biases
- output_lay/MatMul
- output_lay/Add
- output_lay/output_lay

Comment: post some of your c++ code..

Comment: up date result log

Comment: I solved by reading the result message.

Comment: the saving code L2 : "shape=train_data.shape" is not correct. I fixed it to "shape=[None, train_data.shape]".

Comment: Did you figure out how to get the node name in C++ ?